# How to extract image from PGP key on command line?

Tags: sh, gnupg, pgp

I've created a private PGP key and then added a photo to it in my Ubuntu's Passwords and keys manager. I can see the photo there, but is there any way to view it from shell and export it as image file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To view the image, use this:

```
gpg --list-options show-photos --list-keys \
  [key identifier (e-mail or ID), leave out to show all keys and photos]
```

It internally uses `xloadimage`, which wasn't preinstalled on my Ubuntu 18.04, so you can either install it, or use `--photo-viewer "eog %i"` (expands `%i` to temporary file name).

---

To export the image, I haven't found any simpler way than `cat` the data (if `%i` isn't specified, `gpg` sends image data on stdin) to a file like this:
(`%k` - keyID; `%t` - extension --> filenames like `0x02468ACE.jpg`)

```
gpg --list-options show-photos --photo-viewer "cat > <path>/0x%k.%t" --list-keys [key_identifier]
```

---

One more tip - to show image of every key you use to verify something, put this into your `.gnupg/gpg.conf`:

```
verify-options show-photos
# if you don't have xloadimage:
photo-viewer eog %i
```